# Compile on-the-fly doesn't catch error - why?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using this code...

```
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("Imports System")
        sb.AppendLine("Imports System.Xml")
        sb.AppendLine("Imports System.Data")
        sb.AppendLine("Imports System.Collections.Generic")
        sb.AppendLine("Namespace dValuate")
        sb.AppendLine("Class EvalRunTime")
        sb.AppendLine("Public Function EvaluateIt() As Object")
        sb.AppendLine("{0}")
        sb.AppendLine("End Function")
        sb.AppendLine("End Class")
        sb.AppendLine("End Namespace")

        Dim testCode As String = "Dim d As Decimal = ""a"""

        Dim provider As VBCodeProvider = New VBCodeProvider
        Dim params As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters
        Dim results As CompilerResults
        params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll")
        params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xml.dll")
        params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll")
        params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
        params.CompilerOptions = "/t:library"
        params.GenerateInMemory = True
        results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, String.Format(sb.ToString, testCode))

        sb.Length = 0
        If results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
            For Each err As CompilerError In results.Errors
                sb.AppendLine("Line: " + err.Line.ToString + ", Error: " + err.ErrorText)
            Next
            MsgBox(sb.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why is results.Errors.Count = 0 when I try to set a decimal to a string?

Is there a way to catch this error?

Comment: Is is Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Don't know how `Option Strict` works with dynamic compilation, but it would explain why the code compiles just fine.

Comment: Yes; you need `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Option Strict On` to tell the VB compiler to actually check type compatibility at compile-time.

PS: Consider using Roslyn instead of CodeDom.

Comment: Slapping my head .. of course. Are there any samples of using Roslyn on the fly? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly converting a string to a number is not a compiler error without compiling in strict mode.

Add the switch for option strict to the compiler options:

```
params.CompilerOptions = "/t:library /optionstrict"
```